# xts assignment by reference

Tags: r, data.table, xts, r6

Let's have:

```
library(R6); library(data.table); library(xts)
Portfolio <- R6Class("Portfolio",
                     public = list(name="character",
                                   prices = NA,
                                   initialize = function(name, instruments) {
                                     if (!missing(name)) self$name <- name
                                   }
))

p = Portfolio$new("ABC")
DT = data.table(a=1:3, b=4:6)
X = xts(1:4, order.by=as.Date(1:4))
```

If we assign a `data.table` into the object slot and then modify the external data table, the data table in the object slot is modified by reference as well:

```
p$prices = DT
p$prices
DT[a==1,b:=10] # modify external table
p$prices # verify that the slot data is modified by reference
```

Let's do a similar experiment with `xts`:

```
p$prices = X
p$prices
X["1970-01-03"] <- 10 # modify the external xts
p$prices # observe that modification didn't take place inside the object
```

Assigning `xts` object inside the object slot this way seems to break the link between the slot and external object, unlike with `data.table`.

Is it somehow possible to achieve that `xts` is shared by reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what you show is really related to data.table assignment behavior and in any case is related to R6 classes. Indeed, data.table assignment is done by reference( independently that this is copied in R6 field) or xts object are just copied.

**Are you looking to create an xts object as a shared object between all your Portofolio objects?**

Here an exemple:

```
    XtsClass <- R6Class("XtsClass", public = list(x = NULL))
    Portfolio <- R6Class("Portfolio",
                         public = list(
                           series = XtsClass$new()
                         )
    )

    p1 <- Portfolio$new()
    p1$series$x <- xts(1:4, order.by=as.Date(1:4))

    p2 <- Portfolio$new()
```

p2 and p1 share the same xts object. Now if you modify it in p2 you will get the smae modification in p1, since series is a reference object that is shared across all instances of the R6 objects.

```
    p2$series$x["1970-01-03"] <- 10

 p1$series$x
           [,1]
1970-01-02    1
1970-01-03   10  ## here the modification
1970-01-04    3
1970-01-05    4
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, thanks! Also, do you have enough reputation to create new tag `R6` or something (doesn't exist yet), so that it can be added to my question?

Comment: @DanielKrizian r6 tag added.

Comment: I noticed that the memory address changes after the assignment: `A1 = address(p1$series$x); p2$series$x["1970-01-03"] <- 10; A2 = address(p1$series$x); identical(A1, A2) # FALSE` Is therefore writing to `xts` object a costly operation and slower relative to `data.table` approach: `DT[a==1,b:=10]`? Thinking what data structure I should employ

Comment: I don't know exactly what happen behind the scene in R6 objects. Regrading your comment, I think you are looking for a high performance behavior, data.table seems a natural choice. But it is a compromise as usual, if you will manipulate it as time series object (time sub-setting/rolling/) maybe you should use `xts` package. Note also Using Reference classes, will not enhance performance (only memory) but of course  you will get a better designed code.